# Excel ranges typed in with two periods

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Until recently, I was able to specify summing all the cells in column a by using

```
=sum(a..a)
```

which upon pressing enter would automatically convert to

```
=SUM(A:A)
```

Is there a reason this no longer works? Is there a setting I'm missing that got changed on me?

I'm experiencing this on Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0.11328.20478) 32-bit.

Comment: probably was a compatibility item they no longer support.

Comment: "Until recently..." - What version were you using? AFAIK it also doesn't work in Office 2010 either.

Comment: @BruceWayne I listed what version I was using and I only noticed that this was no longer working in the last month or so.

Comment: BTW, this was how entering formulas was taught with the idea that one hand on the letters and one hand on the ten key and you could very quickly input cells and ranges in A1..G<max>.

Comment: [Found this Q&A](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/Cell-Range-Delimiter/m-p/302359/thread-id/22883) finally.


Apparently, this broke when my user account at work was upgraded to Office 365 and that product broke the range delimiter when they added ["Stocks and Geography" data type](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-data-types-stocks-and-geography-61a33056-9935-484f-8ac8-f1a89e210877)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you had a autocorrect setting that changed the `..` to `:`.  If you want it back go to

```
File→Options→Proofing→AutoCorrect Options
```

Then add `..` in the Replace and `:` in the with and hit Add.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the solution as it creates a workaround that restores normal program functionality. However, it absolutely was not an auto-correct function before. This was the way Excel worked for decades.

Comment: I'm removing acceptance of this answer because it now messes with typing ellipsis characters of which three periods in a row was auto-corrected.